# How to grab github repo readme content

Tags: git, github, fetch

How could I grab a github repo's readme's content?

I would like to grab a specific repo's readme, and then it content as well.

How could I do it?

I mean with fetch ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "raw" url to get just the content:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/$user/$repo/$branch/README
```

Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/master/README.rst is the raw url for https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/master/README.rst.